# Unable To See Calculated Field in LocalStorage using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have the following JS code for which I am calculating the insurance cost based on input provided by the user:

```
function AddQuote() {
if (ValidateInputs()) {

    var json = {};

    $(":input").each(function () {
        json[$(this).attr("id")] = $(this).val();
    });

    var nextId = Number(localStorage.getItem('nextId'));
    if (!nextId) {
        nextId = 1;
    }

    localStorage.setItem("quote-" + nextId, JSON.stringify(json));
    localStorage.setItem("nextId", String(nextId + 1));
    $(location).prop('href', 'viewQuote.html?' + nextId);

}
```

}

function LoadQuoteData(id) {

```
var json = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("quote-" + id));

$(":input").each(function () {
    $(this).val(json[$(this).attr("id")]);
});

var driverAge = Number(json['age']);
var driverExperience = Number(json['experience']);
var driverAccidents = Number(json['accidents']);
var subQuote;
var insuranceQuote = Number(json['finalQuote']);

if (driverExperience === 0) {
    subQuote = 4000;

}
else if (driverExperience >= 1 && driverExperience <= 9) {
    subQuote = 2500;

}
else {
    subQuote = 1800;
}

if (driverAge >= 30 && driverExperience >= 2) {
    insuranceQuote = subQuote * 0.75;
}

else {
    insuranceQuote = subQuote;
}

//console.log(insuranceQuote);
console.log(json);

$("#finalQuote").val("$" + insuranceQuote);
```

}
I am using this in my HTML code as follows:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var localStorageItems = Object.entries(localStorage);
        var htmlCode = "";

        $(localStorageItems).each(function () {
            if ($(this)[0].startsWith("quote")) {
                console.log($(this)[0]);
                console.log($(this)[1]);

                var quoteData = JSON.parse($(this)[1]);
                var quoteAmount = "$" + quoteData['finalQuote'];

                htmlCode +=
                    "<div class='container'>" +
                    "<div class='row pb-4 pt-4' style='border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);'>" +
                    "<div class='col-md-6 '>" +
                    "<div class='card-header' style='margin-left: -1rem; margin-right: -1rem;'>Customer Information</div>" +
                    "<span class='d-block'><strong>First Name:</strong> " + quoteData['firstName'] + "</span>" +
                    "<span class='d-block'><strong>Last Name:</strong> " + quoteData['lastName'] + "</span>" +
                    "<span class='d-block'><strong>Address:</strong> " + quoteData['address'] + "</span>" +
                    "<span class='d-block'><strong>City:</strong> " + quoteData['city'] + "</span>" +
                    "<span class='d-block'><strong>Province:</strong> " + quoteData['province'] + "</span>" +
                    "<span class='d-block'><strong>Postal Code:</strong> " + quoteData['postalCode'] + "</span>" +
                    "<span class='d-block'><strong>Phone Number:</strong> " + quoteData['phone'] + "</span>" +
                    "<span class='d-block'><strong>Email:</strong> " + quoteData['email'] + "</span>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "<div class='col-md-6'>" +
                    "<div class='card-header' style='margin-left: -1rem; margin-right: -1rem;'>Driving Information</div>" +
                    "<span class='d-block'><strong>Accidents:</strong> " + quoteData['accidents'] + "</span>" +
                    "<span class='d-block'><strong>Age:</strong> " + quoteData['age'] + "</span>" +
                    "<span class='d-block'><strong>Driving Experience:</strong> " + quoteData['experience'] + "</span>" +
                    "<span class='d-block'><strong>Insurance Quote:</strong> " + quoteAmount + "</span>" +
                    "<span class='d-block'><strong>" +
                    "</span>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "</div>";
            };

        });

        $("#quotesList").html(htmlCode);

    });
</script>
```

But the problem is that the calculated finalQuote is not showing up on this HTML page (but all other fields are).  Any ideas on what I'm missing / not doing correctly?

Comment: Does `finalQuote` get stored on `localStorage`? Where does `finalQuote` get calculated?

Comment: finalQuote is the name of the element that shows the insuranceQuote value.  I recently had finalQuote in place of insuranceQuote in my .js file but it too did not work

Comment: Where would that value be calculated?

Comment: I have finalQuote on another HTML page:              
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="finalQuote">Your personalized Insurance Quote</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="finalQuote" name="finalQuote" disabled>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmit" onclick="AddQuote()" style="color: white">Submit</a>
        </form>
    </main>
</body>

</html>

Comment: Just looking at the code, it seems OK; you could try to add breakpoints at the lines where there is `JSON.parse()` and/or `JSON.stringify()`, in order to see what is being loaded and saved.